# HtmlAgilityPack not working for my WPF project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, html-agility-pack

I am able to use HtmlAgilityPack in a Console Application, but when trying in a WPF app I always get this error on this line `document.DocumentNode.Descendants()` :

```
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode>'.  'Where' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?
```

This is the code :

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            var webget = new HtmlWeb();

            var document = webget.Load("http://google.com");

            var p = from program in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                    where program.Name == "a"
                    select program.InnerText;

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Anyone has an idee why I get that error ?

Thanks.

Comment: But you have a `using System.Linq` in that source file?

Comment: Damm it, I am so ashame, please post it as an answer, and I will accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add:

```
using System.Linq;
```

to your existing using statements near the top of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Add namespace declaration `System.Linq`

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add name space for writing this code ...

```
var p = from program in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                where program.Name == "a"
                select program.InnerText;
```

this was written using linq so you have  to add `using System.Linq;` this namespace